# Dynamically creating Where clause using Expressions

Tags: c#, linq, generics, dynamic, expression

I have to dynamically create a Where clause using expressions in the following manner:

```
Type enumerableType = typeof(Enumerable);
MemberInfo[] members = enumerableType.GetMember("Where*");
MethodInfo whereDef = (MethodInfo)members[0]; 
Type TSource = whereDef.GetGenericArguments()[0]; 
Type[] types = 
{ 
    typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(TSource), 
    typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(TSource, typeof(Boolean)) 
};

MethodInfo method = enumerableType.GetMethod("Where", types);

Expression.Call(null, method , new Expression[]
{
    Expression.Lambda(newEX,new ParameterExpression[]{param})
});
```

The problem I am facing is that at `Expresssion.call` I am getting the following error:

> Method System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TSource]
>   Where[TSource](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TSource],
>   System.Func`2[TSource,System.Boolean]) is a generic method definition

Can some one tell me how to overcome this problem?

P.S: The Expression tree was built by referencing the code generated with reflector. In reflector the code is given as below:

```
Expression.Call(null, (MethodInfo) methodof(Enumerable.Where), 
    new Expression[] ...
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: im trying to dynamically create the Where clause.Any how i have found the mistake. I had to use Method.MakeGenericMethod(); before passing it into Expression.Call()

Comment: If you solved your problem, please post the solution as an answer and accept it. Other users might find it helpful.

Comment: The answer in below link may helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884233/how-to-use-expressions-to-invoke-a-method-call-with-a-generic-list-as-the-parame